# Regex Split String at particular word

Tags: c#, .net, regex, split

I would like to use the [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) `Regex.Split` method to split this input `string` into an `array`. It must group the word.

Input: `**AAA**-1111,**AAA**-666,**SMT**-QWQE,**SMT**-TTTR`

Expected output:

```
**AAA** : 1111,666

**SMT** : QWQE,TTTR
```

What pattern do I need to use?

Comment: General solution for arbitrary number of entries: split by `,`, sort, then split by `-`, then group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comment on the question notes, you cannot do this in a single step (regex or not).

So:

1. Split on commas.
2. Split on dash (but keep the pairs)
3. Group by the first part of each pair.

Something like:

```
var result = select outer in input.Split(",")
             let p = outer.Split('-')  // will be string[2]
             select new { identifier = p[0], value = p[1] }
             into pair
             group by pair.identifier into g
             select new {
               identifier = g.Key
               values = String.Join(",", g)
             }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an IEnumerable with a `key`-string and a string listing (separated by comma) the `values` fore each:

```
var input =  "AAA-1111,AAA-666,SMT-QWQE,SMT-TTTR";

var list = input.Split(',')
                .Select(pair => pair.Split('-'))
                .GroupBy(pair => pair.First())
                .Select(grp => 
                            new{
                                key = grp.Key, 
                                items = String.Join(",", grp.Select(x => x[1])) 
                               });
```

You can then use it for example like this (if you just want to output the values):

```
string output = "";
foreach(var grp in list)
{
    output += grp.key + ": " + grp.items + Environment.NewLine;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW here's the same solution in fluent syntax which might be easier to understand:

```
string input = "AAA-1111,AAA-666,SMT-QWQE,SMT-TTTR";

Dictionary<string, string> output = input.Split(',') // first split by ','
    .Select(el => el.Split('-')) // then split each inner element by '-'
    .GroupBy(el => el.ElementAt(0), el => el.ElementAt(1)) // group by the part that comes before '-'
    .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => string.Join(",", grp)); // convert to a dictionary with comma separated values
```

-

```
output["AAA"] // 1111,666
output["SMT"] // QWQE,TTTR
```